# adding backgroundImage with local image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, inline-styles

I have local images, and I try to set the background image, but it doesn't work for me, everything works fine if the image is hosted, what am I doing wrong?

```
const content = [
  {   
    image: "../../../../assets/images/otdih.jpg",
  },
  {
    image: "../../../../assets/images/otdih.jpg",
  },
  {
    image: "../../../../assets/images/otdih.jpg",

  },
]

  {content.map((item, index) => (
      <div
        key={index}
        className="slider-content"
        style={{
          background: `url('${item.image}') no-repeat center center`,
        }}
       />
    ))}
```

---

**Directory**

```
src/
   /assets/
      /images/
        /otdih.jpg
   /views/
     /homepage/
       /components/
         /uslugi/
           /uslugi.js
```

the paths were correct, I checked paths via `<Image src={require("...")}`

Comment: Most likely the paths are incorrect. Can you show some logs

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert, but when you say 'it doesn't work', do you mean that the image does not appear when you run your app, even though you're sure the file exists at that location in the filesystem?  If so, it's possible that a bundling tool like webpack is moving or renaming your image files, or even converting them to data URLs, in the process of deploying your application. I just had the same problem myself.

You could check this by entering what you think is the image's URL directly in your browser while your app is running, and seeing whether the image loads.

Another way to check is to find a background image that does work and use the browser dev tools to look at its URL.  If the real filename 'assets/images/otdih.jpg' has been replaced with some weird hash generated by a bundling tool ('c16b44cec15f4cecb410.jpg') then you need a way to refer to images in your JS source which is robust against the changes made by the bundling tool. You could be interested in [the question I asked, and found the answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602564), when I had this problem earlier today.