# How can I refer to this external image resource from JS?

Tags: webpack, sass, inline-styles

I have a React app which uses webpack and sass. I am far from being an expert on any of these technologies. The app's `index.scss` uses a background image on the top-level html element, as follows:

```
html {
    ...
    background-image: url('./path/to/image/file.jpg');
    ...
}
```

Using the browser's dev tools I can see that webpack has moved and renamed the image file:

```
background-image: url(http://localhost:6006/c165f4b41cec0.jpg)
```

Now I want to refer to the same image resource in some JS which uses [React inline styles](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

```
const SomeComponent = ()=> (
  <div
    style={{
      ...
      backgroundImage: ??? what goes here ???
      ...
    }}
  >
    Some text here...
  </div>
);
```

How can I robustly refer to the same image resource from JS, regardless of what webpack does with it?

I could transfer the inline style into another scss file, but I would prefer not to as I want to keep this particular JS file self-contained.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the same in inline style also. Just check the image path.

Comment: I tried both `backgroundImage: './path/to/image/file.jpg'` and `backgroundImage: 'url(./path/to/image/file.jpg)'`, neither was replaced by webpack and neither worked because the image does not exist at the original location after deployment... :-(

Comment: Where is your image?

Comment: @ravibagul91, ./path/to/image/file.jpg

Comment: Actually the JS is not using 'inline CSS', it's using 'React inline styles' which are slightly different. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out, so I'm just answering my own question... yuk.

```
import jpgFile from './path/to/image/file.jpg'; // <-- add this import

const SomeComponent = ()=> (
  <div
    style={{
      ...
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + jpgFile + ')', // or `url(${jpgFile})`
      ...
    }}
  >
    Some text here...
  </div>
);
```